Positive monotonic transformation and identical preferences
Two consumers, A and B have the following utility functions
$$ u^{A}(x_1,x_2)=x_1(x_2)^\alpha$$
$$u^{B}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{3}\ln(x_1)+\frac{2}{3}\ln(x_2)  $$
I have to find $\alpha$ such that the utility functions represent identical preferences. When I transform $u^{A}$'s utility function with $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}\ln(x)$ I get that
$$(f ∘ u^{A})(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{3}\ln(x_1)+ \frac{\alpha}{3}\ln(x_2)$$
Which means that when $\alpha =2$, the preferences are identical. However, when I set the equations to be equal
$$\frac{1}{3}\ln(x_1)+\frac{2}{3}\ln(x_2)=x_1(x_2)^\alpha$$
$$ \ln(x_1^{1/3}+\ln(x_2^{2/3})=  x_1(x_2)^\alpha$$
$$ \ln(x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{2/3})=  x_1(x_2)^\alpha$$
$$ \ln(x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{2/3})=  \ln(x_1)+\alpha \cdot \ln(x_2)$$
For logarithms to be equal, I set their arguments to be equal:
$$x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{2/3} = x_1 \cdot x_2^{\alpha} $$
$$x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{2/3} = x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{\alpha} $$
Now the bases are equal, and for the exponents to be equal $\alpha$ is equal to 2/3.
So my question is, which of the ways is the correct one?

You need to find an exponent such that the two utility functions represent the same preferences, not such that they are not equal.
These two functions are clearly not the same.
Recall, however, that utility functions represent unique preference relations only up to monotone increasing transformations, meaning that for any utility function:
$$U(\tilde{x})$$
We can also represent the preferences with any function:
$$\overline{U}(\tilde{x}) = g(U(\tilde{x}))$$
Where $g(.)$ is increasing.
You need, therefore, to find a monotonic transformation of the first utility function that yields a utility function of the form of the second utility function. You're correct that the transformation for this is to take logarthims, and you don't apply it to both functions (you apply $g()$ only to the first function).
$$log(u^A) = log(x_1 x_2^\alpha) = log(x_1) + \alpha log(x_2)$$
This is clearly not quite of the form $u^B$, but it's close. You then need to make an additional transformation, dividing through by $(1+\alpha)$, which is also a monotonic transformation so long as $\alpha > -1$:
$$\dfrac{log(u^A)}{1 + \alpha} = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}log(x_1) + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha} log(x_2)$$.
Finally, then, you can set $\frac{1}{1 + \alpha} = \frac{1}{3} \implies \alpha = 2$.

Consequently, your first solution is correct. The reason your latter method doesn't work is because the utility functions aren't equal, they just represent the same preferences.


However, when I set the equations to be equal

These are not equations, they are functions. You can quite quickly validate that the two functions are not the same function, they are not 'equal', by checking their values at $(1,1)$.
You also write

$$ \ln(x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{2/3})=  x_1(x_2)^\alpha$$
$$ \ln(x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{2/3})=  \ln(x_1)+\alpha \cdot \ln(x_2)$$

but these two equations are not consistent; you only took the logarithm of the right hand side of the first equation.
You also write

$$x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{2/3} = x_1 \cdot x_2^{\alpha} $$
$$x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{2/3} = x_1^{1/3} \cdot x_2^{\alpha} $$

but again, these two equations have little to do with each other, they are not derived from one another.
I recommend sticking to methods that you have discussed in class or going to the office hours of your lecturer to talk through the details of mathematical operations depending on whether you want to pass or get a better understanding.
